# How to forward a UDP port from a devcontainer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, dockerfile, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to use the "Node.js & Mongo DB" devcontainer from Microsoft (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/javascript-node-mongo/.devcontainer) with my udp server made in Nodejs.

The problem is as follows: When i try to forward a port in devcontainer.json example : `"forwardPorts": [1117]`.

It seems to only forward 1117/tcp when i actually want to forward 1117/udp.

I'm trying to making this work for this project : https://github.com/QuentinGruber/h1z1-server/blob/master/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fllowing the documentation you can forward udp protocol with this line

```
docker run -p 53160:53160/udp docker/getting-started
```

So trying add this to your configuration file and should works.

References: [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: While this is correct for the docker cli, this is NOT working for `forwardPorts` settings in a `devcontainer.json`. See other answer for the real solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004668/595764

Comment: Hi @SvenEppler why you want mean by real solution, now exist some bad solution too?

Comment: Your answer ist correct, as long as we are talking about "plain" containers started via command line. DevContainers on the other hand are started by VSCode via a `devcontainer.json` file, therefore a different approach is needed.

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) is kinda fuzzy regarding protocols used for exposed ports with `forwardPorts` tag:

> forwardPorts
>
> - array
> - An array of ports that should be forwarded from inside the container to the local machine.

Because of that I would recommend trying to use the older `appPort` tag because when I looked [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_publishing-a-port) it said they're using the docker-compose syntax which means you can specify the ports and protocol like so:

docker-compose:

```
ports:
- "3000"
- "8921:5000"
```

devcontainers.json:

```
"appPort": [ 3000, "8921:5000" ]
```

### **And in your case:**

```
"appPort": [ "1117:1117/udp" ]
```

According to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_publishing-a-port), using the `appPort` tag is also useful when you want to access the application (or expose the ports) to more than just `localhost`